# Regex: Add words after the second word on the beginning of each line

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this 2 lines:

`Love is the Way is sort of an autobiography, detailing personal stories from Bishop.`

`Love makes the way, no matter what happens, love can change everything.`

I want to add the word "ANYTHING" **after the second word** from each line.

So, my first regex works, this will add the word `ANYTHING` after the first word on each line. GOOD.

FIND: `^(\w+)\K`

REPLACE BY: `\x20ANYTHING`

**BUT now, I try to add after the second word on the beginning of each line:**

FIND: `^(\w+\w+)\K` **OR** `^(\w+){0,2})\K`

REPLACE BY: `\x20ANYTHING`

It is not working. Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You must add a space between the words:

Find what: `^(\w+ \w+)\K`

Comment: thank you @Reddy Lutonadio